# How can i highlight a Month row based on today() in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a 12 rows containing from January to December and 31 columns representing the day of month.

I used the formula `=TEXT(today(),"mmmm")` in cell b1 to get the name of the month ie: August.

How can i change the background color of the whole row of August.

I know i should work with Format->Conditional Formatting:

[image: Check Image]

Sheets is NOT coloring the specific month.

I used: Apply to range A:AF  AND Custom FORMULA is:  $A=$b1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clear any CF from A:AF and try selecting A1:AF14, Format - Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is**:

```
=$B$1=$A1
```

with formatting of your choice.

Assumes your month names are Text.

Selecting the range sets the `Applies to` criteria and since it is often easiest and most versatile (eg regarding insertion and deletion of rows) to choose whole oolumns, the associated formulae will normally need to start from Row1.

Comment: Please enter a valid range when i entered the range A1:AG14
it worked when i used A1:AF14
my question is why did you use Custom formula is: `=$B$1=$A1`
even though cell A1 is empty?